# Display data's from data table on specific way

Tags: c#, sql, web, datatable, display

I have table in database something like this:

| nickname | password |
| --- | --- |
| John12 | 123456 |
| Nick55 | 666777 |

After that, I created a Web Site project, opened the default.aspx page, made a connection... My task is to write a function for the button, which will print the first row of the table (usernames) after 1 click, and the 2nd row (passwords) after the second click.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {}

public int temp;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-UF4RMH6;Initial Catalog=Server;Integrated Security=True");

        try
        {
            konekcija.Open();

            SqlCommand upit = new SqlCommand("select * from Korisnici", konekcija);
            SqlDataReader dr = upit.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Label1.Text += dr[temp] + " ";
            }

            temp++;
            Label1.Text += temp + " ";
            dr.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }
        finally {
            konekcija.Close();
        }
}
```

When I run a site, and try this, it doesen't work, but its perfectly work when I use WindowsForms. Can anyone explain me why and how to solve it.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: In addition, it's a **tremendously bad idea** to be able to show a list of plain text passwords for even a single user, let alone everyone. No person should ever be able to recover the plain text password after its been set.